# Compare specific columns across multiple files and print matched specific column

Tags: join, awk

I have multiple files (six files) in csv format. I am trying to compare $3,$4,$5 across multiple files and if match print $6 from all files along with column $2,$3,$4,$5 from file 1.

Input file 1:

```
Blink,Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0002,VU10,37586764,0.458533399568206
Blink,Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0004,VU08,37687622,0.548181169267479
Blink,Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0006,VU02,6629660,0.553099787284982
```

Input file 2:

```
Farmcpu,Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0002,VU10,37586764,0.907010463957269
Farmcpu,Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0004,VU08,37687622,0.782521980037194
Farmcpu,Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0006,VU02,6629660,0.589126094555234
```

Input file 3:

```
GLM,Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0002,VU10,37586764,0.24089
GLM,Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0004,VU08,37687622,0.25771
GLM,Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0006,VU02,6629660,0.31282
```

Desired output:

```
Trait   Marker  Chr Pos Blink   Farmcpu GLM
Seeddensity(g/cm^3) 2_27144 VU08    36984438    1.7853934213866E-11 0.907010463957269   0.24089
Seeddensity(g/cm^3) 2_13819 VU08    21705264    3.98653459293212E-09    0.782521980037194   0.25771
Seeddensity(g/cm^3) 2_07286 VU01    38953729    3.16663946775461E-07    0.589126094555234   0.31282
```

I have checked multiple awk commands but this is the closest one do a job across two files:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$2,$3,$4,$5]=$1; next } { s=SUBSEP; k=$2 s $3 s $4 s $5 }k in a{ print $0,a[k] }' File1 File2 > output

join <(sort File1) <(sort File2) | join - <(sort File3) | join - <(sort File4) | join - <(sort File5) | join - <(sort File6) > output
```

I believe join is not working as first column is not same across files so I tried this command:

```
join -t, -j3 -o 1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.6,3.6,4.6,5.6,6.6 <(sort -k 3 File1) <(sort -k 3 File2) <(sort -k 3 File3) <(sort -k 3 File4) <(sort -k 3 File5) <(sort -k 3 File6) > output
```

But I am getting an error msg:
join: invalid file number in field spec: ‘3.6’

For two files the following command works, but I am not sure how to use it for multiple files:

```
join -t, -j3 -o 1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.6 <(sort -k 3 File1) <(sort -k 3 File2) > output
```

Comment: You say your input is CSV but the sample input you provided is not CSV (maybe it's tab-separated?). Please correct which ever of those 2 things is wrong, the description or the example, and provide your attempt to solve your problem yourself so we can help you.

Comment: Files are in csv format, i have previously copied from excel so that it can be visualized clearly, i have added some of the codes.

Comment: yeah, never provide some representation of your data, just provide your data so we can provide accurate solutions and copy/paste to test with it. I see you've updated your sample input to CSV but your expected output is not CSV. Is that deliberate and accurate or an oversight? If the latter please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you actually want CSV output then using GNU awk for ARGIND:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{ key = $3 FS $4 FS $5 }
ARGIND < (ARGC-1) {
    val[key,ARGIND] = $6
    next
}
{
    sfx = ""
    for (i=1; i<ARGIND; i++) {
        if ( (key,i) in val ) {
            sfx = sfx OFS val[key,i]
        }
        else {
            next
        }
    }
    print $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 sfx
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file3 file1
Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0002,VU10,37586764,0.458533399568206,0.907010463957269,0.24089
Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0004,VU08,37687622,0.548181169267479,0.782521980037194,0.25771
Seeddensity(g/cm^3),1_0006,VU02,6629660,0.553099787284982,0.589126094555234,0.31282
```

With any other awk just add a line that's `FNR==1 { ARGIND++ }` at the start of the script.

Comment: Many thanks, It worked well for three input files but I have six files in total so if i try to provide six input files it start appeding the output beneathe the output of first three input files

Comment: OK I modified it to work for any number of input files.